# .ogv video not playing on firefox on windows

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, video

I'm implementing a video like this

```
<video id="headervideo" autoplay="" loop="loop" muted="">
    <source src="/data/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/data/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

This plays a video on the following browsers/os

Mac OS X Yosemite: All browsers
Windows 8.1: Chrome & IE
Windows 7: Chrome & IE

However, on Windows on Firefox the video does simply not play and I have no idea why.

This is the info I get from

`curl -I http://myserver.com/data/video.ogv`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 21 May 2015 08:17:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.11 OpenSSL/1.0.1g mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 09:37:21 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 31819481
Cache-Control: max-age=2419200
Expires: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 08:17:01 GMT
Content-Type: video/ogg
```

Comment: have you got the MIME type added in your .htaccess ? `AddType video/ogg .ogv` or added at server level..  What errors are you getting ?

Comment: Hi. I'm not getting an error. The video is just not playing. since the problem only occurs on windows on firefox and not on windows on chrome or mac on firefix I don't think this is a server problem. Also, as you can see. The server is returning the correct mime type

Comment: Actually ic could easily be the MIME type, as the browser will often interpret the correct type and fix the server issue. This is actually common among video files and firefox specifically. Just because your curl can detirmine the MIME type does not mean its permitted from streaming server. At the very least just double check.